# Function Definition: How to make a string say whether or not integer is true or false?

Tags: python, function, definition

Implement the function test_number that takes as input a number and a string:

```
(one of 'even', 'odd', 'positive', or 'negative')
```

The function returns `True` if the number has the property indicated by the string, and `False` if it doesn't.

It works for the even/odd part, so I guess it's gives faulty results for positive/negative because I had put "else: return 'False'" earlier in the function.

Comment: *First of all, what is "assert not"?* I bet this is answered in the preceding chapter of your textbook...

Comment: Return boolean `True` or `False` (no quotes) so that you can can rid of `== 'True'` in the `assert` statements. Also, you need to use `assert not` so you can test that your function fails correctly with e.g. `test_number(100, 'odd')`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks! This was exactly what I was wondering about (the assert not statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, what is "assert not"?

It's an `assert` statement with an expression that starts with the `not` logical negation operator.

> And second of all, why is my code producing false results?

The first `else` reached returns False. Remove all `else` clauses and return `False` at the end, since that will be the default if nothing else is true.

Comment: So I tried putting the else clause at the end (which worked), but when I put assert not statements, an error pops up. If I insert assert statements alone, the code works though. How can I make my code work with assert not statements?

Comment: Don't put an `else`. Just return.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your property strings in a dictionary:

```
def test_number(n, s):
    conditions = {'even': (n % 2 == 0),
                  'odd': (n%2 == 1),
                  'positive': (n >=0),
                  'negative': (n<0)}

    return conditions.get(s, None)

assert test_number(14, 'even')
assert not test_number(100, 'odd')
assert test_number(33, 'positive')
assert not test_number(100, 'negative')
```